# Can’t create YCQL index with WHERE clause in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Can somebody explain to me how to work with indexes metadata in YCQL?
I found this article: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ycql/ddl_create_index/.

And I can't create example INDEX with WHERE condition with this exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: Feature Not Supported
CREATE INDEX idx ON orders (warehouse_id) WHERE warehouse_id < 100
^^^^^^
 (ql error -14)
```

Server: YCQL 3.9.0
Driver: Yugabyte CQL Java Driver 3.8.2
YugabyteDB 2.4.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade to `2.6.x` at a minimum to have that feature. After you upgrade you'll be able to create the index.